# Bot is not removing role on event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

## The problem:

> I'm making an event in py-cord that detects if the user has added a role. If he has administrator permission the bot would let him, and if he only has manage_roles permission the bot would remove the role from the person who got the role. As an example let's say I have only manage roles permission and I want to add to my friend a role, the bot would remove the role from my friend. And If I have administrator permission, the bot would let me

## My code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(after.roles) > len(before.roles):
        # A role was added to the member
        added_roles = [role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles]
        for role in added_roles:
            if role.id == 1093503503680405614:
                # Check if the role ID matches the specified role ID
                updater = after.guild.get_member(after.guild.me.id)
                if updater.guild_permissions.administrator:
                    print("he has admin")
                elif updater.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
                    print("he has NOT admin")
                    await after.remove_roles(role)
```

## Results:

> if I haven't administrator permission the bot would let the user with the role and print("he has admin")

## Traceback:

> except printing "he has admin" the print function that I did define, there is no traceback.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ploblem 1

> `updater = after.guild.get_member(after.guild.me.id)`

[guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.me) will return the member related to your bot's user on that server. So you are setting `updater` to always be your bot. Since your bot probably has admin permission on the server, the conditional will always be true. How to get the user who updated the roles correctly?

#### Problem 2

The [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event only provides the `before` and `after` arguments, which are the `Member` object before and after the update. There is no way to find out who performed the action looking at these objects. The only way to find out who updated the member is to look at the audit log.

#### Solution

You will need to go through the audit log to find out who updated the member's roles. For example, this function returns the latest moderator who updated the provided member's roles:

```py
async def get_role_updater(member):
   """find out who updated this member's roles"""
   guild = member.guild
   action = discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update
   async for entry in guild.audit_logs(action=action, limit=5):
      if entry.target == member:
         return entry.user
```

I haven't tested this code, but assuming it's working as expected, you can simply use this function in your code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(after.roles) > len(before.roles):
        # A role was added to the member
        added_roles = [role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles]
        for role in added_roles:
            if role.id == 1093503503680405614:
                # Check if the role ID matches the specified role ID
                updater = await get_role_updater(after)
                if updater.guild_permissions.administrator:
                    print("he has admin")
                elif updater.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
                    print("he has NOT admin")
                    await after.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: It would be better if you had limit=1 in the audit_logs function, otherwise, pretty much it

Comment: It really is more efficient to adopt a limit. However, using `limit=1` is a bit risky, since if several members were updated at the same time, it is possible that the most recent entry is not about the member that triggered your `on_member_update` event. I recommend adopting at least 5

Comment: Actually yeah, given the chance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this part:

```
added_roles = [role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles]
        for role in added_roles:
            if role.id == 1093503503680405614:
                # Check if the role ID matches the specified role ID
```

In "added_roles", you are adding the role object I think. Maybe try replacing the text in the [ ] with `role.id for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles`

Comment: Well, No. Because I need the person Who gave it, so it doesn't have anything to do with that!

Comment: You just want to check if a person who sent a message has a certain role right?

Comment: No. I want to see who gave role to who